# How to connect my webservice into my umbraco mvc4 application?

Tags: web-services, model-view-controller, umbraco

I want to configure my webservice into my umbraco (mvc4) application. I am new to this umbraco application. Please give an idea to complete the task.

Comment: Could you provide more details? What is your webservice, what is the problem you are experiencing and what have you tried so far?

Comment: if  i create a view in visual studio means, how to get it  in umbraco.

i tried to create a view and partial view in visual studio project of umbraco nuget installed.

after running it i cant see the view page in umbraco developer(macro) section.

please give me a solution.

Actually i need to connect my webservice with umbraco application.

the user entries will send to MSSQL Data Base.

please provide any useful tips.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a [surface controller](https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Mvc/surface-controllers)
So then you for example could do this:

```
public class MyServiceController : SurfaceController{
 public int Add(int a,int b){
  return a+b;
 }
}
```

You can then call your service with the url: /umbraco/surface/MySerivce/?a=1&b=1